# Have anyone seen, warning: target specifies SWIFT_VERSION = '2.3'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I just converted one of my projects from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 and eventhoug everything compiles fine and everything seem to be working I keep getting the following warning...

> > warning: target specifies SWIFT_VERSION = '2.3', but it is overridden by TOOLCHAINS = 'com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault'

Have anyone seen this warning?

Warning:
[image]

Many of the threads I found/read suggest to change the `Command Line Tools:` option to use Xcode 8 but mine is already using `Xcode 8.1(8B62)`

Settings:
[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the some of your dependencies may be specifying swift 2.3. So it is warning you that this may cause problems in the next upcoming update. You also should check the setting for your project and make sure under project settings that the `Use Legacy Swift Language Version' = NO`.

Comment: @ Daniel Leonard - Where can I find the `compile-with-legacy-swift = NO` option?

Comment: Ok, I set  `Use Legacy Swift Language Version' to no then I did a `clean` and the warning disappeared.  `Build Settings > All > Levels > Use Legacy Swift Language Version` and set all options to `no`

Comment: Ya sorry I was commenting from my phone so I couldn't look it up but I'm glad you found it.